# Unity3D how to connect NavMesh and NavMeshAgent

Tags: unity-game-engine, agent, navmesh

I'm getting this error in the editor

`"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.`
These are the steps that I tried when solving the problem:

1. Warping NavmeshAgent to the NavMesh location
2. Manually moving the NavMeshAgent to NavMesh
3. Rebaking the NavMesh and doing the steps above
4. Creating a box with NavMeshAgent and a new NavMesh

   - does anyone have any other tips that I could use?

Comment: Show the script you are using to connect the  NavMesh to the NavMeshAgent

Comment: This is the line that gives the error, nothing wrong with it, I used the same code millions of times before PlantAgent.SetDestination (Player.transform.position); PlantAgent is NavMeshAgent type

Comment: also that same code work in another project, but on this one, I can't set up a NavMesh for some reason

Comment: Is the NavMeshAgent component active? Show us some screenshots of the scene/properties.

Comment: I checked everything, NavMesh is static, agent is active, I have the identical setup working in another project without a problem

Comment: I don't know how to help at this moment. Can you zip the project and upload it somewhere then send the link here. I will take a look at it

Comment: Unfortunately, that would break my NDA. It's really a strange bug that I can't replicate in other projects. I've looked everywhere to some kind of API or function that would allow me to manually pair navmesh and navmesh agent but there is none.

Comment: Usually, you create a simple scene and try to replicate it. If you can't replicate it then that would be hard to fix. I am sure it's not a bug. It's a mistake on your side but who knows...I hope you find a fix for this. Post a solution when you find it

Comment: "Where" did you warp your `NavMeshAgent` to? Could it be its too far above or below the `NavMesh`? Just a wild guess ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warping the Nav Mesh Agents position can sometimes cause errors, especially if it has gone from one navmesh to another.

It's a strange bug, but it seems detecting if the agent is not on the navmesh, and then disabling and re-enabling the agent - will fix the issue (it did in my case).

I've solved this in my project by doing the following when I warp.

```
//use some existing reference to your NavMeshAgent
NavMeshAgent agent = PlayerController.instance.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>(); 

//This will fire when you get the error you're describing.
if (!agent.isOnNavMesh)
{
   Vector3 warpPosition; //Set to position you want to warp to
   agent.transform.position = warpPosition;
   agent.enabled = false;
   agent.enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: That thing solved it!! thanks, Unity should find out why does this happen in projects

Answer (score -3):

we can use the navmesh component 
1. navmesh surface
2. navmesh modifier
3. navmesh modifier volume
4. navmesh offlink 
by using these component we easily connect the navmesh and navmeshagent.